# VueJs - How to use variable in v-if?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am a newbie of VueJs
How to use a variable in v-if??

My js file

```
data: {
    member: [
      {
        id:"1",
        Firstname: "Peter",
        Lastname: "Super"
      },
      {
        id:"2",
        Firstname: "Roger",
        Lastname: "Power",
      }
```

My Html file

then I want to code like this.

```
<li v-for="member in members" v-if="members.Firstname === 'Peter'">
   //display data about id 1 Peter Super
</li>
```

but Is it possible to use a variable in v-if
such as

```
<script>
var name = 'Peter';
</script>
<li v-for="member in members" v-if="members.Firstname === name">
   //display data about id 1 Peter Super
</li>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You access an array by index like `members[0].Firstname`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add that name to your data object then use `find` method inside the template to check if the name is existing :

```
data: {
   name:'Peter',
    members: [
      {
        id:"1",
        Firstname: "Peter",
        Lastname: "Super"
      },
      {
        id:"2",
        Firstname: "Roger",
        Lastname: "Power",
      }
```

template

```
<li v-if="members.find(member=>member.Firstname === name)">
   //display data about id 1 Peter Super
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `key` param also. More here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

```
To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key attribute for each item:
```

Also the issue was in the v-if that you were using `members` instead of `member`

Try the below pls:

```
<li v-for="member in members" :key="member.id" v-if="member.Firstname === 'Peter'">
   //it will display id 1 Peter Super
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line below lists records whose name is Peter only.

```html
<li v-for="member in members.find(item=>item.name == 'Peter')" >
   //display data about id 1 Peter Super
</li>
```