# How to do string interpolation in template element in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, string-interpolation

I am iterating through a dictionary (called in from a .json file) and would like to check an attribute of my `props` with a value in the dictionary. In my first div I am setting the variable attribute to be one of the values in the dictionary. This attribute variable *has the value "event"* which is exactly what I want.

In the inner div, the `props.item.${attribute}` code is not evaluating to `props.item.event`, which is what I thought it would. Is there any way to interpolate the value of this variable to my props statement?

```html
<div
  v-for="data in dict"
  :set="attribute = data.targetAttr"
>             
  <div v-if="props.item.attribute == data.key">
    <a
      :href="data.response"
      target="_blank"
    >
      More Info
    </a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried looking at the resource here, but the answer is only in relation to effectively mapping over lists, which is not exactly my problem.
[VueJs - How to use variable in v-if?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65663571/vuejs-how-to-use-variable-in-v-if)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you should try the following

```html
<div v-if="props.item[attribute] === data.key">
```